# Adding nodes to linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
struct ll 
{
    int data;
    ll *next;
};

void display(ll **head) {
    ll *t = *head;
    while(t){
        cout<<t->data<<"-->";
        t = t->next;
    }
}

void add(ll **head, int d) {
    ll *c = *head;
    ll temp;
    temp.data = d;
    temp.next = NULL; 
    if(*head == NULL) {
        *head = &temp;
    } else {
        while(c->next) {
            c = c->next;
        }
        c->next = &temp;
    }

}


int main() {
    ll *head = NULL;
    add(&head,1);
    add(&head,2);
//add(&head,3);
//add(&head,4);
//add(&head,10);

//display(&head); 
    getchar();
}
```

why does using ll temp in add() not work. if i convert this to  ll *temp= new ll; all w

Comment: Don't you have a debugger?

Comment: i really have no idea howe to use that

Comment: Learn it, it's an essential skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Add() function creates a local ll struct.
Accessing it leads to undefined behavior.
You need to allocate your nodes at the heap section of the memory.

```
void add(ll **head, int d) {
    ll *c = *head;
    ll *temp = new ll;
    temp->data = d;
    temp->next = NULL; 
    if(*head == NULL) {
        *head = temp;
    } else {
        while(c->next) {
            c = c->next;
        }
        c->next = temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: But now ... i can add 1 to the linked list and if i add no other node then it works fine

Comment: But I see what you are saying .. temp is allocated from the stack and goes out of scope

Comment: C++ should use new delete, not malloc free.

Comment: QUESTION REMAINS :  
i can add 1 to the linked list and if i add no other node then it works fine . The display function then works fine. How is that ?

Comment: @stark Thanks, I've forgotten its c++, not c.

Comment: @BhumiSinghal  First You add the local node to the list, then the second call to Add() possibly overwrites it. But anyway it is undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: ohk :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You created a local struct in your function which goes out of scope (all memory is released at the end of the function). However, as you pointed your node to it: `*head = &temp;`, it will cause undefined behaviour as it will point to destroyed memory at the end of the function (once `temp` has gone out of scope), which is unsafe to dereference.

However, if `temp` is allocated with `new`, it means that the `temp`'s will not be destroyed until you call the `delete` keyword, allowing it to be safe to effectively point to a variable created in the function.

Try this:

```
struct ll 
{
    int data;
    ll *next;
};

void display(ll** head)
{
    ll* cur = *head;
    while(cur != NULL){
        cout<< cur->data << "-->";
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

void add(ll** head, int d) 
{
    ll* cur = *head, *temp = new ll;
    temp->data = d;
    temp->next = NULL; 
    if(*head == NULL) {
        *head = temp;
    } 
    else {
        while(cur->next != NULL) {
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        c->next = temp;
    }

}

void free_list(ll** head)
{
    ll* cur = *head, *next = NULL;
    while(cur != NULL){
        next = cur->next;
        delete cur;
        cur = next;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    ll *head = NULL;
    add(&head,1);
    add(&head,2);
    display(&head); 
    free_list(&head);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: i can add 1 to the linked list and if i add no other node then it works fine . The display function then works fine. How is that ?

Comment: @BhumiSinghal - I have added a modified version of your code to my answer which may help

Comment: hey thank you! I can always create the list using pointers.. I got stuck with the local var for obvious reasons .. but thank you so much

Comment: @BhumiSinghal - no problem :)